# I accidently removed /usr. Is there a way to recover it?

Tags: data-recovery

I accidently removed my entire */usr* directory thanks to [RVM](https://rvm.io//). I can still use the terminal prompt with Ctrl+Alt+F6, but I don't have any sudo (I guess it's because of the missing */usr*).

Is there any way to recover my files?, I didn't reboot yet. If not how can I make sudo and the other things work again without completly reinstalling the OS? I'm runnig Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have backups => Yes

If you haven't made backups, start making them while you remember why it is important.

I think the easiest solution is to make a copy of your home directory and /etc onto an external disk, then detach the external disk and do a reinstall of the system.
If you have enough storage space on an external disk:

- start a liveCD
- copy *all* files to external disk or at least /home and /etc
- reïnstall
- copy the files from your backup to the new install
- compare the config files in /etc with the ones in your backup

Comment: Alright, then I'll do a complete reinstallation again. It's just a bit frustrating because I keep destroying my system every few weeks . :S

Comment: You can wait for a little while to check for other answers. And this is exactly why I advise to make regular backups.

Comment: I was busy making one but i got the same advice: reinstall! Just think of it as a lesson learnd :)

Comment: Also you're obviously using `root` privileges way too often. Try to minimize that to the very least possible. See it as a challange :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method: backup your own files from a live cd and re-install. It is also the most efficient and less time consuming.

Difficult methods:

- you can install a Ubuntu system on another system and copy the files from that system over to your machine.
- Use a [data recovery tool like R-Studio for Linux](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/) to recover it.

  R-Studio for Linux recovers files:

  - Deleted from the computer and emptied from the Trash
  - Corrupted due to a virus, power failure or sudden shutdown
  - From disks that have been Re-formatted to the same file system or a different file system
  - Damaged and have bad sectors-R-Studio for Linux creates an image of the entire disk and recovers it from there to prevent further physical damage to the disk